# Android Bluetooth Service to Transfer data between devices

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, kotlin, bluetooth

Hello am new in Android development I was reading about android bluetooth [Here on Android development  documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/transfer-data).
I was able to setup bluetooth, find the bonded device and to connect but am having an issue on transfer data between them
Here is the bluetooth server socket code that listen to bluetooth connection request.

```
class BluetoothActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var listen: Button
private lateinit var msgBox:TextView
private lateinit var status:TextView
private lateinit var sendButton: Button
private lateinit var writeMsg:EditText
private lateinit var listDevice:Button
private lateinit var listView: ListView
private val handler = Handler()
private var bluetoothDevices = arrayListOf<BluetoothDevice>()
private var deviceName = arrayListOf<String>()


private inner class ServerAcceptThread:Thread(){
    private val mmServerSocket:BluetoothServerSocket? by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE){
        bluetoothAdapter?.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(myName,myUUID)
    }

    override fun run() {
        //Keep listen until error occured or socket is returned
        var shouldKeepListen = true

        while (shouldKeepListen){
            val socket:BluetoothSocket? = try {
                mmServerSocket?.accept()
            }catch (e:IOException){
                Log.e("bluetoothSocket","ServerSocket failde",e)
                shouldKeepListen = false
                null
            }
            if (socket!= null){
                val connected = ConnectedThread(socket)
                connected.start()
            }
        }
    }

    //Close server socket and cause the thread to finish
    fun cancel(){
        try {
            mmServerSocket?.close()
        }catch (e:IOException){
            Log.e("ConnectionFailed!", "Connection close failed",e)
        }
    }
}
```

And down below is the code for Bluetooth client that connect to bluetooth server socket.

```
private inner class ClientConnectThread(device: BluetoothDevice):Thread(){
    private val mmSocket:BluetoothSocket? by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE){
        device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID)
    }

    public override fun run() {
        //Cancel the discovery process because it slow down the connection
        bluetoothAdapter?.cancelDiscovery()

        mmSocket?.let { socket ->
            socket.connect()
        }
    }

    fun cancel(){
        try {
            mmSocket?.close()
        }catch (e:IOException){
            Log.e("Socket", "Could not close the client socket",e)
        }
    }
}
```

And Then I have bluetooth service that read and write data to send to remote device (client). which take BluetoothSocket as parameter, were the server is listening to

```
    private inner class ConnectedThread(private val mmSocket:BluetoothSocket):Thread(){
        private val mmInPutStream:InputStream = mmSocket.inputStream
        private val mmOutPutStream:OutputStream = mmSocket.outputStream
        private val mmBuffer:ByteArray = ByteArray(1024)

        override fun run() {
            var numByte:Int //number of bytes returns from read()

            //keep listen to the InputStream until an error occured
            while (true){
                //Read from inputStream
                numByte = try {
                    mmInPutStream.read(mmBuffer)
                }catch (e:IOException){
                    Log.e(TAG,"InputStream was disconnected",e)
                    break
                }
                //Send the message to Ui activity
                val readMsg = handler.obtainMessage(
                    MESSAGE_READ,numByte,-1,mmBuffer
                )
                readMsg.sendToTarget()
            }
        }

        //Call this function to mainActivity to send data to remote device
        fun write(byte:ByteArray){
            try {
                mmOutPutStream.write(byte)
            }catch (e:IOException){
                Log.e(TAG,"Error occured during send messge",e)

                //Send the failed message back to activity
                val writeErrorMessage = handler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_TOAST)
                val bundle = Bundle().apply {
                    putString("Toast","could not send the data")
                }
                writeErrorMessage.data = bundle
                handler.sendMessage(writeErrorMessage)
                return
            }

            //Share the sent message with UI activity
            val writtenMsg = handler.obtainMessage(
                MESSAGE_WRITE, -1,-1,mmBuffer
            )
            writtenMsg.sendToTarget()
        }

        //Call this method to activity to shut socket
        fun cancle(){
            try {
                mmSocket.close()
            }catch (e:IOException){
                Log.e(TAG,"Connection closed failed!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I have also implement the listener for UI to start listen to a connection request, list Bonded device and connect to remote device and transfer data through each other.

```
fun implementsListeners(){
    listDevice.setOnClickListener {
        val pairedDevice: Set<BluetoothDevice>? = bluetoothAdapter?.bondedDevices
        var index:Int = 0
        val pairedDevice: Set<BluetoothDevice>? = bluetoothAdapter?.bondedDevices
        if (pairedDevice != null){
            var listDeviceName = arrayListOf<String>()
            try {
                pairedDevice.forEachIndexed { index, device ->
                    listDeviceName.add(index, device.name)
                    bluetoothDevices.add(device)
                }
            }catch (e:IndexOutOfBoundsException){
                Log.e(TAG, "indexOutOfBond",e)
            }
            val arrayAdapter:ArrayAdapter<String> = ArrayAdapter(
                this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listDeviceName
            )
            listView.adapter =arrayAdapter
    }

    listen.setOnClickListener {
       val serverClass = ServerAcceptThread()
        serverClass.start()
    }

    listView.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
        val client = ClientConnectThread(bluetoothDevices[position])
        client.start()
        status.text = "Connecting..."

    }

    sendButton.setOnClickListener {
        val client = BluetoothService(Handler())
        //Call the write() method to write data

    }
```

My Question is how can I access the write() method and read() that is on ConnectedThread. I have tried to Instantiate ConnectedThread but it's take BluetoothSocket as parameter I can't access the socket outside client or server class. Method Any help or suggestion on. I would Appreciate

Comment: The server calls close() as soon as a client is accept()ed. That looks wrong.

Comment: `And Then I have bluetooth service that read and write data to communicate` Is that for the server or the client? Please edit you post.

Comment: `And I have also implement the listener for UI to interact with Bluetooth class` Is that for the server or client? Please update your post.

Comment: @blackapps hello the server keep listen on while(shouldKeepListen) == true otherwise the server port should close.Unlike TCP/IP, RFCOMM it only allow one connected client per channel so it's appropiate to call close
inorder to release the socket

Comment: Well you close the server socket right away. So a connected client is immediately closed. I can not see it different. After that the socket tries to listen again for a new client. But if every client is closed right away then all makes no sense.

Comment: @blackapps so should I check if the socket is open  inorder to allow client to connect

Comment: The socket is closed so there is nothing to check. You should not close the serversocket right away.

Comment: @blackapps so when should I close the server? I appreciate the effort and help you provide to me and sorry for my English

Comment: You should close the server when the time has come that you do not want to accept new clients and also when all active clients are ready and closed the connection. Probably at closing your app. But do not close a server socket when there is an active client. Don't be that rude ;-)

Comment: @blackapps now I understand, I have update the code but the problem is I have EditableText I have name writeMsg. I have setOnclick listener on send Button that get text from writeMsg converts toByte but how do I access write() method from class ConnectedThread without instantiate it because it require BluetoothSocket as parameter

Comment: You have not reacted on my second and third comment.

Comment: @blackapps on ui I have three button listen,ListDevice and sendButton on listen button I have set listener and call serverClass = ServerAcceptThread().start. And on listDevice listener I have call bonded device and put on listView then I have another listener onItemClickListener. where I call Client class client = ClientConnectThread(bluetoothDevices[position]).start

Comment: You have not reacted on my second and third comment.

Comment: @blackapps okay I think I understand you for the case of bluetoothService. I have created class ConnectedThread That read and write data to remote device. And takes BluetoothSocket as parameter which use socket that server its listen on. an in UI the is button for listen, Which can be used as Server to open a port to allow client to connect to.

Comment: You talk and talk. Please edit your post.  First post all the server code. After that post all the client code. At the moment it is mixed i think. Hard to follow. Make it clear where your client code starts.